# Computer vision to read words/numbers on curved surface

Tags: computer-vision

Is it possible for computer or machine vision to read words or numbers on curved surface? For example, expiry dates on eye-drops or medical vials. I have identified 1 item but I am not sure if it works.

JEVOIS-A33 SMART MACHINE VISION CAMERA - DEVELOPER / ROBOTICS KIT
https://www.jevoisinc.com/products/jevois-a33-smart-machine-vision-camera-developer-robotics-kit?variant=38829907210

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. What you are looking for is called "Transform invariant text detection (or extraction)" and there are many models that can do this with varying rates of success.

You can read more about it in [Text Detection and Recognition in Imagery: A
Survey](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6945320).